# Bootstrap - Table - Codeigniter Filter Control

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter-3, filtro, bootstrap-table

Que tal amigos tengo una duda utilizo la extension https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/filter-control.html
para crear en las columnas de mi tabla Select con filtrados
Es decir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema esta conectado a una Base de datos el cual extraido la informacion de una table con la siguiente extructura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Manejo las rutas:

```
Controlador/Items.php
Modelo/item.php
Vista/item/manage.php
```

Dando como resultado la primera imagen de ejemplo.
mi pregunta es la siguiente.

**¿Cómo le indico a Controlador y al Modelos que al seleccionar un atributo del select de alguna de las columnas me filtre la table y me muestre la informacion deseada?**

Por ejemplo

Si selecciono en Grupo la categoria FORD automaticamente se carga la table con todos los datos que estan en ese grupo. Al igual si selecciono Grupo FORD y Marca TIPO ORIGINAL se muestre en la tabla todos los datos relacionados a ello.
Solo utilizo una tabla para tener esa informacion. GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO